# SSH connection over internet works only for specific machines

Tags: ssh

I have a WLAN with my laptop (kubuntu), a raspi (rasbmc) and a fritzbox 3370 as gateway. I can stablish a ssh connection from my laptop to the raspi when I use the local IP (192.168.X.Y). But if I try to connect over the internet I get "Conection time out". The weird thing is that I can establish a ssh connection to my laptop over the internet (with adjusted port forwarding) with my smartphone. Same happens with http on port 80.

My Setup:

- WLAN: laptop, raspi, fritzbox3370
- Dyndns: provider noip.com, client installed in raspi, it's working
- Port forwarding at fritzbox: from port 30000 to raspi on port 22
- Firewall of raspi is disabled

Overview of ssh connections:

- laptop to raspi over WLAN (not leaving my local network) works
- smartphone to laptop over Internet works (independant if smartphone is in
- wlan or using mobile network)
- laptop to raspi over internet does not work (using dyndns ip)

Helmsen

Comment: Did you port forward the raspi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rasbmc is a hardened version of the OS, you will need to modify your iptables to allow for traffic outside your subnet to connect to port 22.  There are a few ways to do this but a simple 'iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT' above the 'iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP' line located in the /etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc should work.

Comment: After changing /etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc I had to restart raspi. Then it worked, thanks! But it's weired, because actually I disabled firewall via rasbmc gui.